# Create a dictionary from pandas dataframe modifying the structure

Tags: python, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am pretty new with python and all of this stuff, at the moment I have a csv file uploaded inmemory with Django rest framework, so far so good at this point, now I need to insert this data into the DB so I need to get the columns accordingly my models, so I need to convert this csv to a mapping object, I am loading the file using Pandas, so my function is something like:

```
def insert(self, request):
    
    
    file=codecs.EncodedFile(request.FILES.get("file").open(),"utf-8")
    reader = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=";")
    reader.columns = ['regions_trips','origin_coord','destination_coord','datetime','dataSource_trips'];
    size=int(reader.shape[0])+1
    index = pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=size, step=1, name="no_record")
    reader_index= reader.set_index(index)
    print("Dataframe reader_index=",reader_index)
    
    reader_json=reader.to_json(orient = 'records')
    print(reader_json)
    #serializer = DataSourceSerializer(data=)
```

So when I call the API, send the file and try to see how is the output of the file converted to json is something like:

```
[
{
    "regions_trips": "Prague",
    "origin_coord": "POINT (14.4973794438195 50.00136875782316)",
    "destination_coord": "POINT (14.43109483523328 50.04052930943246)",
    "datetime": "28\/05\/2018 9:03",
    "datasource": "funny_car"
},
{
    "regions_trips": "Turin",
    "origin_coord": "POINT (7.672837913286881 44.9957109242058)",
    "destination_coord": "POINT (7.720368637535126 45.06782385393849)",
    "datetime": "21\/05\/2018 2:54",
    "datasource": "baba_car"
}]
```

but how I am expecting the output is:

```
[
{
    "regions_trips": "Prague",
    "dataSource_trips": {
        "origin_coord": "POINT (14.4973794438195 50.00136875782316)",
        "destination_coord": "POINT (14.43109483523328 50.04052930943246)",
        "datetime": "28\/05\/2018 9:03"
    },
    "datasource": "funny_car"
},
{
    "regions_trips": "Turin",
    "dataSource_trips": {
        "origin_coord": "POINT (7.672837913286881 44.9957109242058)",
        "destination_coord": "POINT (7.720368637535126 45.06782385393849)",
        "datetime": "21\/05\/2018 2:54"
    },
    "datasource": "baba_car"
}
```

I am not sure how I can put those "columns" (not sure how call them) into a new element called dataSource_trips.

My dataframe looks like:

```
Dataframe=    regions_trips                                 origin_coord                           destination_coord          datetime     dataSource_trips
0         Prague   POINT (14.4973794438195 50.00136875782316)  POINT (14.43109483523328 50.04052930943246)   28/05/2018 9:03            funny_car
1          Turin   POINT (7.672837913286881 44.9957109242058)  POINT (7.720368637535126 45.06782385393849)   21/05/2018 2:54             baba_car
```

Hope you have enough information to help me :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by merging the three columns into a single column.

```
print("Dataframe reader_index=",reader_index)
datasource_cols = ["origin_coord", "destination_coord", "datetime"] 
reader['dataSource_trips'] = reader[datasource_cols].to_dict(orient='records')
reader = reader.drop(datasource_cols, axis=1)

reader_json=reader.to_json(orient="records")
```